# Псевдоэлемент прячется за фон

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/yaroslav2292/pen/JxvMGm?editors=1100
Попробуйте нарушить путь картинки, чтобы картинка убралась с доски, тогда появится квадрат, но мне нужно, чтобы этот квадрат был рядом с картинкой и его было видно,а не чтобы он прятался за ней.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.granny-img {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 92px;
}

.granny-img::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 175px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  border: 2px solid #AFAFAF;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-img">
  <img class="granny-img" src="https://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/1000_1x_/public/images/2018/06/edinburgh_meadows_2008_middle_meadow_walk_by_catharine_ward_thompson.jpg?itok=ysmDaSjD&fc=50,50" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что псевдоэлемент before задан для тега <img/>, который является самозакрывающимся (не имеет потомков, не содержит текст). Нежелательно использовать псевдоэлементы для подобных тегов - input,br,img и тд.

В данном случае лучше создать дополнительную обертку для тега img, или использовать существующий div с классом header-img, а затем позиционировать с помощью css.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.granny-img {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 92px;
}
.granny-img__wrap{
  position:relative;
}
.granny-img__wrap::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  border: 2px solid #AFAFAF;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header-img">
<span class="granny-img__wrap">
      <img class="granny-img" src="https://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/1000_1x_/public/images/2018/06/edinburgh_meadows_2008_middle_meadow_walk_by_catharine_ward_thompson.jpg?itok=ysmDaSjD&fc=50,50" alt=""></span>
    </div>
```